# Configure nginx to serve manifest.json file in web app

Tags: nginx, manifest, progressive-web-apps

In my web app, I have this error in the dev console:

```
GET /manifest.json 401 (Unauthorized)
manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token.
login:1 Site cannot be installed: the manifest could not be fetched, is empty, or could not be parsed
```

If I call the json file directly in the browser url, it's ok, but my app can't call this file because nginx returns a 401 error:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
```

[image]

How can I allow this file in nginx?

Comment: Have you checked this same issue in [github](https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/issues/6962)?

Answer (score 21):

In my case, this error resolved after I added the crossorigin attribute:

```html
<link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json" crossorigin="use-credentials">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This should be accepted as an answer.